# How to use a command output as input for grep in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which derive lots of data from multiple logs files each day. Furthermore I created another script which will do more processing on that data and grep a string and give a count with `grep -c`.

I have tried below mentioned way but second script not taking input from first output

```
./myfirstsctipt | ./mysecondscript
```

How my second script will use first script output as input for grep script?

I have tried using `firstscript` as argument for second like below but did not work.

```
./mysecondscript $(./myfirstsctipt )
```

Even its not working with cat as first command  my file content is like that

```
TIME+2019-10-25 00:09:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:12:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:13:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:16:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:18:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:20:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:22:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:26:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:27:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:28:11.184
TIME+2019-10-25 00:30:11.184
```

and `mysecondscript` is

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -vx

for hour in `seq -w 0 23`
do
  for min in `seq -w 0 59`
  do
    a=`grep -c "$hour:$min:"  `
    echo "$hour:$min   $a"
  done
done
```

I am trying like below.

```
cat test2 | ./mysecondscript.sh
```

Comment: `./myfirstsctipt |./mysecondscript` should work if your scripts are correct. Can't say anything more without seeing them.

Comment: The first does what you are asking if the second script reads the parameters on standard input, the second if it wants command-line arguments. If neither works then something else is wrong. Quoting? What does the actual data look like? Could it contain erroneous DOS line terminators?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: i have updated the question will all details

Comment: Tagentially see also [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read standard input more than once. The first iteration consumes all the input in the first invocation of `grep -c` and subsequent iterations will simply draw the proverbial blank.

You could solve this with a temporary file (the idiom is `t=$(mktemp -t foo.XXXXXXXX) || exit; cat >"$t"; trap 'rm -f "$t"' ERR EXIT` and then `grep -c regex "$t"` as many times as you like) but you want to avoid temporary files if you can - and anyway, in this case, a much more efficient solution is to only read the input once.

```sh
awk '{ t[substr($2, 1, 5)]++ }
  END { for(h=0; h<24; h++) {
    hh = sprintf("%02i", h);
    for(m=0; m<60; m++) {
      mm = sprintf("%02i", m);
      printf("%s:%s %i\n", hh, mm, t[hh ":" mm]) } } }'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/MjyzXR